# Framework7 component not works in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, html-framework-7

I want to add [f7-timeline](https://v1.framework7.io/vue/timeline.html) component in my Vue app.

I added Framework7 and Framework7Vue in my app.js file. Other Framework7 components like `<f7-button>` and `<f7-progressbar>` works properly. But when I use `<f7-timeline>`, give this error in console :

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/pages/timeline/timeline.vue
>
> ```
>  <F7View>
>     <F7App>
>       <App> at src/app.vue
>        <Root>
> ```

```
<template>
    <f7-page>

        <f7-timeline>
            <f7-timeline-item day="21" month="DEC" inner content="Some text goes here"></f7-timeline-item>
            <f7-timeline-item day="22" month="DEC" inner content="Another text goes here"></f7-timeline-item>
        </f7-timeline>

        <f7-button>Button Text</f7-button>
        <f7-progressbar :progress="20"></f7-progressbar>
    </f7-page>
</template>
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f7-timeline` is used by ***Framework7 Vue.js V1*** and its deprecated. in the Latest Version (4.1.1) you can display your timeline using normal HTML like this:

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-item-date">21 <small>DEC</small></div>
    <div class="timeline-item-divider"></div>
    <div class="timeline-item-content">
      <div class="timeline-item-inner">
        <div class="timeline-item-time">12:30</div>
        <div class="timeline-item-title">Title</div>
        <div class="timeline-item-subtitle">Subtitle</div>
        <div class="timeline-item-text">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-item">
    ... another timeline item ...
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information,  you can check the ***Framework7 Vue.js Kitchen skin*** for [timeline](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-vue/blob/master/kitchen-sink/src/pages/timeline-horizontal.vue) demo.